# How do I enable hibernation on Wubi?

Tags: wubi, hibernate, swap

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 Sager laptop using Wubi. Hibernate (i.e. suspend to disc) is not an option from the power icon, only suspend, shutdown, etc. Hibernate is also not an option from my battery/lid close options. I understand that hibernation is disabled by default in Ubuntu 12.04. I tried running pm-hibernate but I get the following message:

```
Looking for splash system... none 
s2disk: Snapshotting system
```

and then the computer just hangs with a black screen. According to the documentation [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394) if this fails then I can't enable hibernate but it offers no help in making pm-hibernate succeed.

Could swap be my problem? It looks like I have very small swap:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk            file        262140  0   -1
```

The advice on [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) is only for the author's set up (e.g. I don't have an Ubuntu install disk since I used Wubi) and he says that 'INFO: This will not work for 12.04, resume from hibernate work differently in 12.04.'

Any advice? I really need to get hibernate working to use my laptop as a, er, laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, hibernation is not supported for Wubi systems (see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)).

If you want to be able to hibernate your Ubuntu system, you'll have to do a standard installation (alongside, instead of inside, your Windows system) by booting from an Ubuntu CD/DVD or USB flash drive and running the installer.

[bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) has [explained this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224718/change-swap-amount-to-hibernate-in-wubi#comment277364_224718) further:

> You can't hibernate a Wubi install unless you also have a swap
>   partition. You're using a swap file so increasing the size won't help.
>   There is a way to hibernate with a swap file, but I've never seen
>   anyone get it to work on Wubi.