# a step away from hibernate!

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, power-management, hibernate

I'm having trouble enabling my hibernate feature.
I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit using Wubi on my Asus N53SN hybrid laptop ( Intel + Nvidia). After Updating through ubuntu Update manager AND turning off my Nvidia card using Bumblebee, I no longer have an issue with suspending (aka standby, right?) my laptop and the laptop fan running at the full speed all the time. Oh and I also installed Jupiter and have set it on power saver ( CPU temp= 48 centigerades. is it ok?). any ways, I thought these were important to know in order for my problem to be solved.

So when I tried to hibernate using uswsusp, it seemed like ubuntu was doing some things, the colorful screen went black with white texts, it didn't turn off; but everything went back to normal (but there were no sound/wireless problem). having a 8gb ram, I checked my swap size and I thought that I should increase it. I did that using this code that is available on the WubiGuide:

```
sudo su
swapoff -a
cd /host/ubuntu/disks/
mv swap.disk swap.disk.bak
dd if=/dev/zero of=swap.disk bs=1024 count=2097152
mkswap swap.disk
swapon -a
free -mrm swap.disk.bak
```

(I thought 2gbs is ok since I won't have 2gb of applications running to take ram memory. maybe I am wrong here.)
then, I try :
`sudo s2disk`
but I get:

> s2disk: Could not use the resume device (try swapon -a). Reason: No such device

I do what he (!) asks, but nothing happens. I again try to run s2disk, but I get the same error.

can you help me out? I think since I have no trouble with with suspend then I am just one step away from having hibernate.

EDIT: I came across this question [How do I enable hibernation on Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144877/how-do-i-enable-hibernation-on-wubi)

I didn't think that this would interfere. So there is no way to hibernate with a swab FILE?